# Баг при быстром прокручивании Infinite scroll

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, прокрутка

Внедрил Infinite Scroll на своем сайте для просмотра товаров. Вроде все работает, но при быстром скролле загружаются повторные товары и т. д. При медленном же все работает. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы запрос отправлялся скажем каждые две секунды? Поставить задержку в двух словах. Страница: https://stockup.az/browse. Вот код:

```
var start = 0;
var limit = 4;
var reachedMax = false;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var md = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height() - 80;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > md)
        getData();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
});
```

И функция getData()

```
function getData() {
if (reachedMax)
    return;

$.ajax({
    url: '../pages/data.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        getData: 1,
        start: start,
        limit: limit
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == "reachedMax")
            reachedMax = true;
        else {
            start += limit;
            $(".results").append(response);
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете завести глобальный флаг `allowLoading`, который будет устанавливаться в `false` при начале загрузки и в `true` при ответе сервера. Заодно это даст возможность избавиться от переменной reachedMax:

```
var start = 0;
var limit = 4;
var allowLoading = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var md = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height() - 80;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > md)
        getData();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    if(!allowLoading) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '../pages/data.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            getData: 1,
            start: start,
            limit: limit
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "reachedMax") {
                allowLoading = false;
            } else {
                start += limit;
                $(".results").append(response);
                allowLoading = true;
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            // На случай если произошла ошибка сети
            allowLoading = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Не сработало, после этого вообще перестало что либо показываться

Comment: Собрал тестовый кейс — работает корректно. Вы точно всё перенесли из моего примера?

Comment: Да, скопировал. Еще есть файл data.php, если поможет, могу скинуть.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jZUGrtzGRBDyt5zt1fTu7XKHJ1HlOP3X/view?usp=sharing — загрузил тестовый кейс архивом. data.php (изменил путь к нему в js, также удалил расчёт высоты футера, тк его нет на странице) просто возвращает рандомное число и добавляет в конец `.results`